# AppGuyver Steroids/Supersonic app freezes when using camera from view opened by tab-bar item under “more” tab

Tags: steroids

I'm having trouble with views which are accessible via the menu which is available under the 'more' button on the tabs bar. Every time I use e.g. a barcode scanner, or camera to take a picture from a view accessed through this menu, my app freezes.

When accessing the same view from a tab bar item directly on the tab bar and using the same code, my app does not freeze.

I'm using:

- node v0.10.36
- steroids v4.0.12
- AppGuyver Scanner 4.0.3
- iPhone 4 w/iOS 7.1.2

To replicate this issue:

```
steroids create testapp
cd testapp
steroids update
steroids generate module camera (Select "Javascript" to be generated.)
steroids connect
```

Fire up an editor and edit testapp/config/structure.coffee. Insert a tab in the 2nd position
of the tab bar to access the camera module like this:

```
tabs: [
{
  title: "Index"
  id: "index"
  location: "example#getting-started" # Supersonic module#view type navigation
}
{
  title: "Camera"
  id: "camera"
  location: "camera#index"
}
{
  title: "Settings"
  id: "settings"
  location: "example#settings"
}
{
  title: "Internet"
  id: "internet"
  location: "http://google.com" # URLs are supported!
}
]
```

Edit testapp/app/camera/scripts/IndexController.js and make sure it contains the following code:

```
angular
.module('camera')
.controller('IndexController', function ($scope, supersonic) {
    $scope.takePicture = function () {
        var options = {
            quality: 50,
            allowEdit: true,
            targetWidth: 300,
            targetHeight: 300,
            encodingType: "png",
            saveToPhotoAlbum: true
        };
        supersonic.media.camera.takePicture(options).then(function (result) {
            // Do something with the image URI
        });
    };

});
```

Edit testapp/app/camera/views/index.html and make sure it contains the following markup:

```
<div ng-controller="IndexController">

   <super-navbar>
    <super-navbar-title>
        Index
    </super-navbar-title>
</super-navbar>

<div class="padding">
    <h1>Pow! Here's your fresh module!</h1>
    <button class="button button-block button-positive icon-left super-wand" ng-click="takePicture()">Take picture
    </button>
</div>
```

Save all files. Then, from the terminal window in the testapp folder, run:

```
steroids connect
```

This should open up your browser with the Steroids Connect QR showing. Fire up the AppGuyver scanner on your device. Scan the QR code from the screen. This should fire up your app.

Click the 2nd tab (no icon is shown, just the text "camera" but this does not matter). It opens up the camera module's view. Click on 'Take picture'. Make a photo and confirm you want to use the photo. The app returns back to the camera module's view. All is well for now... So the camera works.

Now go to your terminal window and exit steroids. In the shell, execute the following commands:

```
steroids generate test1
steroids generate test2
```

Now change the testapp/config/structure.coffee file again and edit the tabs like so:

```
tabs: [
{
  title: "Index"
  id: "index"
  location: "example#getting-started" # Supersonic module#view type navigation
}
{
  title: "Settings"
  id: "settings"
  location: "example#settings"
}
{
  title: "Internet"
  id: "internet"
  location: "http://google.com" # URLs are supported!
}
{
  title: "Test 1"
  id: "test1"
  location: "test1#index"
}
{
  title: "Test 2"
  id: "test2"
  location: "test2#index"
}
{
  title: "Camera"
  id: "camera"
  location: "camera#index"
}
]
```

Save files again. From the terminal window, type:

```
steroids connect
```

Scan the QR code shown in your browser again to run the app.

Using the tabs bar, press the 'more' button (with the three dots on the utmost right position). A new menu opens. Now click on one the 'Camera' menu item. This will fire up the camera module's view. Click on 'Take picture'. Make a photo and confirm you want to use the photo.

The app now hangs. The same happens when you cancel taking a picture.

I've also reproduced this on an iPhone 5s, iPad 2 (when adding extra tab items). The log shows this for the last lines:

```
camera#index    10:33:53.534    debug   "supersonic.media.camera.takePicture called"
camera#index    10:33:48.514    debug   "supersonic.ui.navigationBar.setStyleId resolved"
camera#index    10:33:48.490    debug   "supersonic.ui.navigationBar.setStyle resolved"
camera#index    10:33:48.453    debug   "supersonic.ui.navigationBar.update called"
camera#index    10:33:48.438    debug   "supersonic.ui.navigationBar.setStyle called"
camera#index    10:33:48.472    debug   "supersonic.ui.navigationBar.setClass resolved"
camera#index    10:33:48.554    debug   "supersonic.ui.navigationBar.show resolved"
camera#index    10:33:48.465    debug   "supersonic.ui.navigationBar.show called"
camera#index    10:33:48.552    debug   "supersonic.ui.navigationBar.update resolved"
camera#index    10:33:48.449    debug   "supersonic.ui.navigationBar.setStyleId called"
camera#index    10:33:48.390    debug   "supersonic.ui.navigationBar.setClass called"
```

Any idea what can be the issue here?

Kind regards,

Eric

Answer (score 1):

AppGyver developer here – it sounds like a probable native-side bug. We used to have more serious issues with tabs accessible via the "More" button, see [here](https://github.com/AppGyver/steroids/issues/116), so this might stem from the same thing.

Can you post an issue to our issue tracker at https://github.com/AppGyver/steroids/issues – preferably with a cloud-deployed app that reproduces this?

Comment: Done here: https://github.com/AppGyver/steroids/issues/857. Thanks for responding.